# java ant application. unable to build under linux

Tags: java, linux, java-7

I have java sources that I can build on windows machine using ant.
When I clone sources to linux machine and try to run 'ant local' cmd I get errors like this:

```
[javac] /home/pi/production-stand/1.4.1.0/src/com/google/protobuf/GeneratedMessage.java:209: error: type argument BuilderType#1 is not within bounds of type-variable BuilderType#2
[javac]       extends AbstractMessage.Builder<BuilderType> {
[javac]                                       ^
[javac]   where BuilderType#1,BuilderType#2 are type-variables:
[javac]     BuilderType#1 extends com.google.protobuf.GeneratedMessage.Builder declared in class com.google.protobuf.GeneratedMessage.Builder
[javac]     BuilderType#2 extends com.google.protobuf.AbstractMessage.Builder<?> declared in class com.google.protobuf.AbstractMessage.Builder
[javac] /home/pi/production-stand/1.4.1.0/src/com/google/protobuf/GeneratedMessageLite.java:62: error: type argument BuilderType#1 is not within bounds of type-variable BuilderType#2
[javac]       extends AbstractMessageLite.Builder<BuilderType> {
[javac]                                           ^
[javac]   where BuilderType#1,BuilderType#2 are type-variables:
[javac]     BuilderType#1 extends com.google.protobuf.GeneratedMessageLite.Builder declared in class com.google.protobuf.GeneratedMessageLite.Builder
[javac]     BuilderType#2 extends com.google.protobuf.AbstractMessageLite.Builder<?> declared in class com.google.protobuf.AbstractMessageLite.Builder
[javac] /home/pi/production-stand/1.4.1.0/src/ru/omnicomm/fas/tester/Config.java:183: warning: DOMParser is internal proprietary API and may be removed in a future release
[javac]             DOMParser dom = new DOMParser();
[javac]             ^
```

I use eclipse under windows which pointed to c:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_40:

```
c:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_40\bin>java.exe -version
java version "1.7.0_40"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_40-b43)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 24.0-b56, mixed mode, sharing)
```

jdk used on linux machine is same:

```
    $ java -version
java version "1.7.0_40"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_40-b43)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 24.0-b56, mixed mode)
```

What can lead for this error?

Comment: can you provide us with full commands? Are you sure that the libraries you are compiling against are the same?

Comment: We avoided this problem just by using compilied under windows jar files in linux.

Comment: This has absolutely nothing to do with the system the jar is built on, please do not provide misleading answers